# IP address consumption in private VPC Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Problem description :

1. Created a VPC and created 4 subnets [2 public and 2 private].
2. Created an RDS (Multi-AZ) instance. Then created a subnet group too and pointed it to the already created VPC and private subnet.

My Question:

I did install 2 instances in the public subnet and none in private except for the RDS subnet which I pointed it to the already created Private subnet. When I was going through the number of IP's consumed, I saw 2+ IPs consumed in public (which is ok) and nothing in private. My question is how come the created RDS instance is not consuming the IP from the private subnet I had created?

Comment: *"When I was going through the number of IP's consumed,"* Where exactly are you looking, and what exactly do you see?  Also, familiarize yourself with what's found under **Network Interfaces** in the left-hand navigation pane of the EC2 console.  Anything with an address in your VPC supernet (EC2, ELB/ALB, Lambda, RDS, EFS, ...) should be visible there.

Comment: What IP addresses are assigned to the RDS instance? What is the CIDR for the VPC and the subnets?

Comment: Are you looking at elastic IP addresses ? Because you will only see the public static ip addresses over there.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Thanks for that information. I didn't know we can look in that place to see the consumed IP'S, But the problem(my question rather) still remains the same. I did see  EC2 taking 2 public IP's, ELB's taking 2 IP's and RDS instance taking 2 (coz of multi-az).

Comment: @JohnHanley
When I go to the VPC dashboard and click on subnet under available IPV4, 
I see  2x56 available for 2 public subnets and 2x58 available for 2 private subnets. 
VPC CIDR is 10.0.0.0/24
Subnet CIDR is 10.0.0.0/26 x 4

Comment: @SukenShah,
 I am not looking at elastic IP at all, coz my question is in regards with private IP's consumed by RDS. Let me know If I still need to look into it.

Comment: I wish I could attach a screenshot of the problem and make it easier for all.I think some limitations with my user account, bcoz I am new to StackOverflow.